# Create two entities with the second one depending on the first in entity framework

Tags: c#-4.0, entity-framework-5, objectcontext

i have a class library in c# and entity framework that has a payment model.

My payment model have one table called `Payment`, and then another table called `PaymentSolid`, this last one saves the solid values of the first one like if the first one have `IdSeller`, then the seccond one have `SellerName`.

My question is that i have a method called `NewPayment` where i create the `Payment` entity and the `PaymentSolid`.
I have the next code in my method:

```
Payment ret;
        using (var context = new MyEntities())
        {
            ret = new Payment
            {
                id_buyer = IdBuyer,
                id_seller = IdSeller,
                id_seller_bill_to = IdSellerBillTo,
                id_payment_method = IdPaymentMethod,
                creation_date = CreationDate,
                payment_status = PaymentStatus,
                notes = Notes
            };
            context.Payments.AddObject(ret);
            context.Refresh(RefreshMode.StoreWins, ret);
            var retSolid = new PaymentSolid { 
                buyer_name = ret.Buyer.ProviderName,
                seller_name = ret.Seller.ProviderName,
                seller_bill_to_name = ret.SellerBillTo != null ? ret.SellerBillTo.ProviderName : null,
                payment_method_name = ret.PaymentMethod.name
            };
            ret.PaymentSolid = retSolid;
            context.SaveChanges();
            context.Refresh(RefreshMode.StoreWins, ret);
        }
        return ret;
    }
```

And my question is if i can use the `ret.Buyer.ProviderName` to create the solid or if i have to save the `Payment` first to then create the solid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `id_buyer` to create the relationsip between `Payment` and `Buyer` you'll need to save `ret` first.

Comment: Thats what i thought... i will try that.